# Error: Unable to resolve module react-native while using pnpm workspaces

Tags: react-native, symlink, metro-bundler, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

I have been developing monorepo setup using pnpm workspace where I am trying to integrate a react native mobile app. The app is using a shared package where all the common ui elements are stored.
I have found a recent article which shows react native has support for symlinks now [metro-package-exports](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2023/06/21/0.72-metro-package-exports-symlinks#enabling-beta-features).
metro.config.js

```
/**
 * Metro configuration for React Native
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */
module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    unstable_enableSymlinks: true,
    unstable_enablePackageExports: true,
  },
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: true,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
  },
  
};
```

Still, I am getting the same error like this -

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=myapp/.MainActivity }
 BUNDLE  ./index.js

error: Error: Unable to resolve module react-native from D:\ProjectWork\Project\R4\my-app\20230803 - mobile\myapp\apps\mobile\ReactNative\myapp\index.js: react-native could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  ..\..\..\..\node_modules
  3 |  */
  4 |
> 5 | import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
    |                            ^
  6 | import App from './App';
  7 | import {name as appName} from './app.json';
  8 |
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (D:\ProjectWork\Project\R4\my-app\20230803 - mobile\my-app\node_modules\.pnpm\metro@0.76.7\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:139:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (D:\ProjectWork\Project\R4\my-app\20230803 - mobile\my-app\node_modules\.pnpm\metro@0.76.7\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:277:43)
    at Object.resolve (D:\ProjectWork\Project\R4\my-app\20230803 - mobile\my-app\node_modules\.pnpm\metro@0.76.7\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:169:21)
    at Graph._resolveDependencies (D:\ProjectWork\Project\R4\my-app\20230803 - mobile\my-app\node_modules\.pnpm\metro@0.76.7\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:473:35)
    at Graph._processModule (D:\ProjectWork\Project\R4\my-app\20230803 - mobile\my-app\node_modules\.pnpm\metro@0.76.7\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:261:38)
    at async Graph._traverseDependenciesForSingleFile (D:\ProjectWork\Project\R4\my-app\20230803 - mobile\my-app\node_modules\.pnpm\metro@0.76.7\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:249:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Graph.initialTraverseDependencies (D:\ProjectWork\Project\R4\my-app\20230803 - mobile\my-app\node_modules\.pnpm\metro@0.76.7\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:233:5)
    at async DeltaCalculator._getChangedDependencies (D:\ProjectWork\Project\R4\my-app\20230803 - mobile\my-app\node_modules\.pnpm\metro@0.76.7\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\DeltaCalculator.js:229:25)
    at async DeltaCalculator.getDelta (D:\ProjectWork\Project\R4\my-app\20230803 - mobile\my-app\node_modules\.pnpm\metro@0.76.7\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\DeltaCalculator.js:112:16)
```

dependencies in package.json -

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.9",
    "react-native-gradle-plugin": "^0.71.19",
    "react-native-webview": "^12.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.72.3"
}
```

metro version in package-lock.json - metro: 0.76.7
Can anyone help with this ?

I have tried steps shown in the article which shows react native has support for symlinks now [metro-package-exports](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2023/06/21/0.72-metro-package-exports-symlinks#enabling-beta-features).
I have tested the app in android emulator.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to resolve it.
This was my project structure.

```
apps
   - mobile-app ( react native )
     - folder1
        - folder-react-ui
     - samplereactapp
        - samplereactapp-subfolder
           - metro.config.js
   - web-app (react)
node_modules
packages
   - shared-package
pnpm-workspace.yml
```

Modified the metro.config.js like this -

```
const {getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig} = require('@react-native/metro-config');
const path = require('path')
/**
 * Metro configuration
 * https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration
 *
 * @type {import('metro-config').MetroConfig}
 */
const config = {
  watchFolders: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../../node_modules'),
  ],
  resolver: {
    unstable_enableSymlinks: true,
    unstable_enablePackageExports: true,
  },
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: true,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
  },
};

module.exports = mergeConfig(getDefaultConfig(__dirname), config);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: `unstable_enableSymlinks` was exactly what I needed. Thank you!